# GUI message box in SLES 11

Tags: suse, dialog, zenity

I am using SLES 11 and I often run long processes.
I am looking for a method to flash an alert box or a message box when the work is done.

In Ubuntu there is `zenity` which can flash an info box. I am looking for similar functionality for SUSE/SLES. I saw there is `dialog` but I dont think this opens a GUI box.

Any ideas ?

**ADDED INFO**
I dont have `root` on the machine (neither do I want a clumsy $USER install). I want to use something that is native to SLES.

Comment: Install `zenity`?

Comment: I dont have `root` on the machine (neither do I want a clumsy $USER install). I want to use something that is native to SLES. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `xmessage`. Nothing fancy - basically very simple X `dialog` equivalent - but for displaying alert it should do. And it doesn't depend on any advanced toolkits (GTK+, Qt and such).

`notify-send` (part of libnotify) can to similar thing but integrated with the desktop environment - it tells the DE to display a pop-up message (it is present in SLE11 SP3).

Comment: I think this is what I need. Perfect !! Kudos !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an xterm-window for this. There you can set it to flash on inactivity (or play a sound, or ...).